# How do I remove the captiona and border of a window, and how do I make my custom style UI?

Tags: c++, winapi

I was wondering if it's possible to remove the border and caption of a window. I have done this before but I cannot recall what style I used.

Also, how would you go about to make your own UI with fully resizable components. I'm working in C++ at the moment. An example of this "custom UI" would be kinda like Winamp so I'm wondering if this is possible in C++ (with any library or alike).

Comment: See: Qt (http://qt.nokia.com/products/)

Comment: try c++builder and the vcl (for the UI) http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder. As an aside you can just toggle a couple of properties and your form has no border or caption using the vcl.

Comment: +1. Qt is the best for cpp))) i worked both with vcl and qt. for my opinion qt is much more powerful

Comment: Please reconsider. The world does not need more UI like WinAmp.

Comment: I am not planning on making something like WinAmp. Just so you would understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 3):

To create window without caption & border just set style to WS_POPUP instead of WS_OVERLAPPED when create your window:

```
CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_POPUP, x, y, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```